# Topic explosion in mirrormaker 2

Tags: apache-kafka, replication, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

Does mirrormaker 2 need 6 system topics (on both sides of the wire) for each topic to be replicated? I am concerned this could lead to topic explosion. we need two-way sync between kafka clusters

Comment: There's a heartbeat topic and an offsets topic. What other 4 are you referring to? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=95650722#KIP382:MirrorMaker2.0-InternalTopics

Comment: The link is pointing to an empty page. can I have the correct link please? we have, mm2-configs, mm2-offset-syncs, mm2-offsets, mm2-status, checkpoints.internal, heartbeats. so a total of 6 topics

Comment: Hmm. You're right. Anyway search KIP382, and it explains all the internal topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three of those topics are for Kafka Connect, not MirrorMaker2 (configs, offsets, and status}.

No, none of those are unique to each mirrored topic, but rather the Kafka Connect cluster and its group id. You can run multiple mirrors in the same Connect cluster, thereby not creating new set of internal topics.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you @oneCricketeer: The topics "mm2-configs, mm2-offset-syncs, mm2-offsets, mm2-status" are created by Kafka connect? Since MM2 relies on Kafka connect, they are required? we can run multiple MM instances in the same Kafka cluster?

Comment: Just `mm2-configs, mm2-offsets, mm2-status`. You can find the purpose of those topics defined here - https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/config/connect-distributed.properties#L37-L62 And yes, you can run multiple Kafka Connect workers that host `MirrorSourceConnector` tasks